# js seems not to be able to find my form

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="poll"> 

    <h1>Poll</h1>
    <form name="pollvoteform1" method="post" xxaction="/plugins/content_types/poll/poll.php">
    <p class="tekstaanmelden"><b>Het regent </b></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="poll" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="">
            <div class="pollOption"><input type="radio"  class="stelling" name="poll_option1" value="1"></div><div class="pollOptionText">Eens</div><br clear="all"><div class="pollOption"><input type="radio"  class="stelling" name="poll_option1" value="2"></div><div class="pollOptionText">Oneens</div><br clear="all"><div class="pollOption"><input type="radio"  class="stelling" name="poll_option1" value="3"></div><div class="pollOptionText">Waar</div><br clear="all"><div class="pollOption"><input type="radio"  class="stelling" name="poll_option1" value="4"></div><div class="pollOptionText">Niet waar</div><br clear="all">
            <input type="button" name="bt_submit" class="pollButtonNormal" onmouseover="this.className='pollButtonHigh';" onmouseout="this.className='pollButtonNormal';" value="Stem" onclick="javascript:vote1();" style="padding-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 5px;">
            <input type="button" name="bt_submit2" class="pollButtonNormal" onMouseOver="this.className='pollButtonHigh';" onMouseOut="this.className='pollButtonNormal';" value="Bekijk resultaten" onclick="javascript:viewResults1();"  style="padding-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 5px; width:98px;">
    </form>
</div>
<div style="display:none;width: 175px;">

    <form><input type="button" name="bt_submit" class="pollButtonNormal" onmouseover="this.className='pollButtonHigh';" onmouseout="this.className='pollButtonNormal';" value="Resultaten" onclick="javascript:viewResults1();" style="padding-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 10px; "></form>
</div>
```

In my script I have:

var r=document.forms.pollvoteform1.poll_option1;

But I get the error:

document.forms.pollvoteform1 is undefined
And I don't understand why. Since the pollvoteform1 and the poll_option_1 are both there.

//update: the full js code

```
    function vote() {
var r=document.forms.pollvoteform1.poll_option1;
var voted=false;
if (r.value!=null && r.checked){
voted=true;
} else {
for (i=0;i<r.length;i++){
if (r[i].checked) {
voted=true;
break;
}
}}

if (voted) {
document.forms.pollvoteform1.submit();
} else {
alert("you didn't make a choice yet");
}
}
```

Comment: Not seeing a problem with your posted code so it might be elsewhere, but I strongly advise using id attributes and getElementById where possible.

Comment: You where right. I forgot to close a different form on the same page :-(

Comment: can you update your title to say javascript instead of js and add the browser and version as well.  That makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its either

```
var r=document.forms['pollvoteform1'].poll_option1;
```

or if that dosnt work

```
var r=document.forms[0].poll_option1;
```

Comment: the first option gave the same error.
By the second one I get:

r is undefined

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to do but maybe you want var r=document.forms[0].poll_option1.value;

That would make r = 2

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an ID tag to the form. It should be the same as the name tag.

Comment: also add ids to the input (e.g. poll_option1)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in IE7 and Firefox 3.0.10.

Which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using firefox (latest version)